# custom directive's link function is invoked before ng-repeat is replcaed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-directive, angular-directive-link

I have the following directive:

```
.directive("picSwitcher", ["$timeout", function($timeout){
return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
        pics: "=",
        fadeTime: "@",
        timeForPic:"@"
    },
    template: '<img ng-repeat="pic in pics" src="{{pic.url}}" style="display: none"/>',
    link:   function ($scope, element){
                //some code...
                $(element.find("img")[0]).css({display: "block"});
            }
};
}])
```

my problem is, when my link function is invoked - ng repeat is yet to "compile" (what word should be used here instead of compiled?)

so I am trying to set css of undefined..
how can I force the link function to run after ng-repeat finished?!

for now I am solving this by replacing `$(element.find("img")[0]).css({display: "block"});` with `$timeout(function(){
$(element.find("img")[0]).css({display: "block"});}, 200);`

but that feels 'hacky'

is there something I am missing to achieve my goal in an easier way?
in general, what is the best way to manipulate ng-repeat dom element inside the link function of a custom directive?

Thanks,
Jimmy.

Comment: maybe if you will do the template inside the html and not in the directice it will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check `$scope.$evalAsync`

```
$scope.$evalAsync(function(){
    $(element.find("img")[0]).css({display: "block"});
}
```

This will make the function executed after the dom rendering.

Also, using $timeout is not a bad idea if u set the delay to 0

```
$timeout(function(){
    $(element.find("img")[0]).css({display: "block"});}, 
0);
```

will also do the trick i think.

More reference http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2605-scope-evalasync-vs-timeout-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: Thanks, according to your reference, in my situation it is better to use the $evalAsync method :) but I am happy to see I wasn't doing very wrong things. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQLite's `.ready()` function.

```
    post: function postLink(scope, element) {
      element.ready(function() {
        //$(element.find("li")[0]).css({color: "red"});
        element.find("li:first-child").css({color: "red"});
      });
    }
```

I also changed the way you select elements in your directive. Since you have `element` available you can just use JQLite. However, to just change a css class, you should do it in a CSS file.

In the snippet below I replaced `<img>` with `<ul><li>` but it works the same for images.

```js
function myDirective() {
  return {
    template : '<ul><li ng-repeat="pic in pics">{{pic.name}}</li></ul>',
    scope: {
      pics: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
        element.ready(function() {
          //$(element.find("li")[0]).css({color: "red"});
          element.find("li:first-child").css({color: "red"});
        });
    }
  }
}
function SuperController() {
 this.pics = [{name:"rob"}, {name:"jules"}, {name:"blair"}];
}
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('SuperController', SuperController)
    .directive('myDirective', myDirective);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="SuperController as s">
    <my-directive pics="s.pics">
    </my-directive>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: seems like it. don;t know why!! Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: I think this is a better answer than the accepted anser